# Running JUnit test from IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 generates ClassNotFoundException

Tags: intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception, intellij-2020

Running a JUnit test from IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 generates the following error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.android.repository.api.ProgressIndicator
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.repository.api.ProgressIndicator
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidManifestMergingTarget$MyTargetType.computeAllTargets(AndroidManifestMergingTarget.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildTargetRegistryImpl.<init>(BuildTargetRegistryImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

The test runs successfully if I run it via Maven, but it fails using IntelliJ IDEA button.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 bug.

Updating the IDE version to **2020.1.1** fixes the problem.